# find descendant buttons in nested container

Tags: swift

I have placed buttons in multiple nested StackViews

I then placed the views within a CollectionView (yes I recognize this isn't necessarily the best or optimal way to do this).

**I'm trying to figure out how I can programmatically find all my buttons.**

If I do this, all I get is my StackView instead of getting the buttons (which are now 3rd level descendants).  I'd love to not have to right a nested loop and instead find a function that helps me find all descendants of type UIButton.

```
        for subview in buttonContainer.subviews {
            let button = subview as? UIButton
            if button != nil {
                button!.setTitle("TEST", for: UIControl.State.normal)
            }    
        }
```

The reason I'm doing this is just as an exercise to learn different methods, which is why I am ok nesting multiple stack views and then placing them within a CollectionView

Answer (score 1):

I didn't test it but using recursion you should be able to accomplish this. Something like this may work for you:

```swift
func findButtonsIn(_ view: UIView) -> [UIButton] {
    var buttons: [UIButton] = []
    view.subviews.forEach({
        if let button = $0 as? UIButton {
            buttons.append(button)
        } else {
            buttons.append(contentsOf: self.findButtonsIn($0))
        }
    })
    return buttons
}
```

**Usage**

```swift
findButtonsIn(yourView)
```

The function will return all found `UIButtons` as an array.

You could use

```swift
self.findButtonsIn(UIView()).enumerated().forEach({
    $0.element.setTitle("\($0.offset)", for: .normal)
})
```

for example to set the buttons title according to the order they were found in.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a **`recursive method`** like:

```
func buttonsIn(_ view: UIView) {
    if let button = view as? UIButton {
        button.setTitle("TEST", for: .normal)
    } else {
        view.subviews.forEach({ buttonsIn($0) })
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
buttonsIn(view)
```

Modify the `recursive method` as per your requirement.